# Gson serialization: can I do it from the JSON String or I need to use JsonWriter?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm using the Google [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson) library for handling JSON strings. I need to save this strings in files (save/load operations).

In particular, when I have a class `MyClass` that includes a set of parameters (integers, String, array of primitive types, etc.), e.g.

```
public class MyClass{
 int val;
 int[]vals;
 String text;

 public MyClass(){}
}
```

I can transform a `MyClass` object in a JSON string as follow:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
//obj->set...
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Now! Should I create the `String json` and save it in a file as usual or should I use the [`JsonWriter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do both.

Yet using `JsonWriter` will offer better performance: the output can be streamed into the file instead of mapping the whole output in memory before writing it into the file.

Using a `BufferedWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(obj, new JsonWriter(bw)); // Write to file using BufferedWriter
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will use `JsonWriter` then :) Performance is always important! +1